# How to define a type to computed properties in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm new to typescript and i'm converting my javascript code to typescript so I can learn type script.

I have this below code and I'm receiving a typescript warning error at [context!.label] which indicates that a computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.

My question is how I can fix this and why typescript is giving this warning error?
I thought that typescript differs not so much from javascript?

Thank you in advanced for the explanation.

```
private initializeJoiError = (error: Joi.ValidationError) => {
   this._JoiError =
     {
        status: "failed",
        validationErrors: {
             details: _.map(error.details, ({message, context}) => {
             return  {**[context!.label]** : message.replace(/['"]/g, "")}
             })
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NdodXw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type):

```
//...
return {
  [context!.label] : message.replace(/['"]/g, ""),
} as Record<typeof context['label'], string> //or whatever type that is
```